# Graph Editor Shows No Keyframes

Tags: interface, keyframes, graph-editor

Trying to use the graph editor but I see no keyframes to an existing camera path. I want to eventually alter the speed of the camera path by manipulating the keyframes in the graph editor. How do I find / reveal the keyframes in the graph editor?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method to find keyframes in the Graph Editor or Dope Sheet is to disable the "[Show Only Selected](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html#view-controls)" filter. With that off keyframes on all non hidden objects will show, not just the selected object(s) which is the default.
The button right next to it (dashed square icon) is the *Show Hidden* filter. With that off (as shown in the image below) all keyframes will display.

[image: Show Only Selected in the graph editor]

Comment: Thanks. That did it.  Cheers.